# How to answer correclty to POST request with PHP

Tags: php, post, curl

I have a **POST** request in java, with the following parameters:

```
localHttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
localHttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
```

Lets suppose I want to answer string `$some`.
How do I need to encode it in order to answer correctly to the request?

I thought of:

```
echo utf8_encode(urlencode($some));
```

But it doesn't work..

I appreciate any help

Comment: could you give a more detailed error report than "But it doesn't work..". What is the output? What is the error? What is your suspected result? what is the actual result?

Answer (score 0):

To encode url in Java:

```
string = URLEncoder.encode(string, "UTF-8");
```

It will use `+` for the space. But if you want the spaces into `%20` then replace `+` as well.

```
string = URLEncoder.encode(string, "UTF-8").replaceAll("\\+", "%20");
```